# What was the point of bringing back a token from David's brothers in 1 Samuel 17:18?

Tags: 1-samuel

1 Samuel 17:18
English Standard Version

> Also take these ten cheeses to the commander of their thousand. See if your brothers are well, and bring some **token** from them.”

Was the token suppose to confirm David's errand? Was there a trust issue between the father and son?

Answer (score 1):

The operative word in 1 Sam 17:18 is עֲרֻבָּה (arubbah) which, according to BDB means:

> עֲרֻבָּה noun feminine thing exchanged, pledge, token; — suffix
> עֲרֻבָּתָם 1 Samuel 17:18 = a token from them, i.e. response, token of
> welfare, Th Dr and others; absolute as accusative of congnate meaning
> with verb ׳עָרַב ע Proverbs 17:18 give a pledge.

Note that עֲרֻבָּה (arubbah) only occurs in 1 Sam 17:18 and prov 17:18 (by a strange numerical coincidence!)

Thus is a reference to a common custom, still practiced today of bring news via a token and perhaps a letter.  Note the various comments about this:

- Cambridge: "take their pledge] Bring home some token from them that they are well: the equivalent of a letter."
- Barnes: "Take their pledge - i. e., bring back what they have to say in return."
- Matthew Poole: "Take their pledge, i.e. bring me some token of their welfare from them."
- Jamieson-Fausset-Brown Bible Commentary: "take their pledge—Tokens of the soldiers' health and safety were sent home in the convenient form of a lock of their hair, or piece of their nail, or such like."